# How to invoke Fragment's onOptionItemSelected before Activity's?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using **SlidingMenu** implementation in my app, I want the **android.R.id.home** button to open/close the side menu. Inside the Activity I use Fragment to display information. I want the home button to act as a back button.

The problem is that **Activity's onOptionsItemSelected** in Activity get invoked before the **Fragment's** one. Is this ordinary behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my project as well, but I don't think that matters tho.

Is implementing my own interface the only solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly last night I was struggling with this but eventually managed to solve it, so here is my solution:
These are the relevant parts from MainActivity:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here is my menu main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

and here is my Fragment:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class TestFrag extends SherlockFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, android.R.id.home, 100, "Home");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
//            Do whatever you want when Home is clicked.
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Home is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting:
[image: Menu items from both the parent activity and the fragment.]

I hope this helps in any way.

Comment: Although this doesn't really solve the problem I'm having. This is probably a good idea in some other case. I've never thought of doing this before.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up moving the onOptionsItemSelected from Activity to my base Fragment class instead.

Inside base fragment class, I have these:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Toggle slide menu
            getBaseActivity().getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected boolean useHomeAsBack(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.v(TAG, "useHomeAsBack - onOptionsItemSelected");
            getSherlockActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside `onAttach` as well.

Inside the actual Fragment that I wanted to use back instead, I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(useHomeAsBack(item)) return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Still, I'd expect Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected to be able to override or take priority over Activity's. Wonder what the reason for that would be.